# why a frame opens at new tab alone without menu

Tags: html, frame, frameset

when i work at the same tab, everything is fine, but when i ctrl+click one of the link from left site, it will be opened at the new tab alone without "menu.html". i mean i don't want the pages without menu side at the new tab.
is there any way to do that?

here is index html:

```
<frameset cols="20%,*" frameborder="1">
<frame name="menu" src="menu.html" noresize="noresize" />
<frame name="main" src="main.html" noresize="noresize" />
```

here is menu.html (left side):

```
<table>
<tr><td><a href="content.php" target="main">Link 1</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="result.php" target="main">Link 2</a></td></tr></table>
```

Comment: The best solution is to not use frames.

Comment: what can i use instead of frames?

Comment: just use an include and only write it once, especially since php is being used

Comment: if you want it to stay static, just use a fixed css element

Answer (score 0):

You can consider HTML frames as a separate browser window i.e. Frames divides the browser window into multiple windows. Thus, when you open a link from a frame into new tab (Ctrl+Click), the new tab will display the html page from the link which is not having frameset.

To achieve the behavior you have mentioned in your question, you need to use frameset in all your web pages. This can be achieved using Master Page in ASP .NET.

Comment: i will probably try to prevent opening a new tab